# NSPredicate contains string lowercase

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I'm developing an iOS application with iOS SDK 6.0 and XCode 4.5.2. My target development is 4.3.

I'm using Core Data to manage my data. Now I have this `NSPredicate` to search shops:

```
if ((shopSearchBar.text != nil) && ([shopSearchBar.text length] > 0))
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@",shopSearchBar.text];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
}
```

This is Shop entity:

[image]

I have to convert **name** to lowercase and see if it contains `shopSearchBar.text` in lowercase format.

Example:

I have these four shops:

- Shop1
- shop 1
- my shop
- Shop

If user search text is 'shop', it must returns all of them.

**Do you know how to do that?**

Answer (score 73, accepted):

This is how I've solved my problem:

```
if ((shopSearchBar.text != nil) && ([shopSearchBar.text length] > 0))
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@",
                              shopSearchBar.text];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
}
```

Comment: You do not need to check `text` for _nil_. Write just `if (shopSearchbar.text.length)`, it will return _nil_ in both cases either text is nil or empty string.

Answer (score 2):

(a) You could add a column to your repository - lowercaseName - and every time you save a Shop, save a lowercase only version of it's name. Then your predicate is just compare :)

(b) However, if all you want is to do a case insensitive compare try this :

```
if ((shopSearchBar.text != nil) && ([shopSearchBar.text length] > 0))
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name LIKE[cd] %@",shopSearchBar.text];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
}
```

This is also diacritic insensitive compare. Look at the String Comparison section of [this docs page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html) for more options.

(a) gives you faster queries but more complicated code.
(b) gives you very simple save methods but (slightly) slower queries

Comment: I don't know if I'm doing something wrong but it doesn't work.

Comment: You're doing something wrong then ;) Do you have an example of a search someone is doing and the Shop it should match? And have you tried BEGINSWITH instead of LIKE - it might help?

Comment: I've added an example to my question to show what I want to do.

Comment: I guess try all of the different string compare predicate methods until you find the one that does that then i.e. LIKE, BEGINSWITH etc. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use NSPredicat's predicateWithBlock: method:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id obj, NSDictionary *bind) {
return [self.name compare:shopSearchBar.text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame; }];
```

Comment: NB - This isn't available if the underlying store is SQLite - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001187-DontLinkElementID_1

Comment: Thanks a lot , i have been searching from looong time :) (y)